# Microsoft Edge and Windows mobile download my product page instead of showing it normally

Tags: .htaccess, download, prestashop, microsoft-edge

I'm developping an online shop with PrestaShop 1.6.1 on an Apache server. I have no problem with Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But on Microsoft Edge (on my computer) and on my Windows Phone, the product pages does never show up. All other pages are ok, the issue is only when I try to open a product page with Edge or with my Windows Phone.

What is the issue? What can I do to solve it?

Comment: well, sounds like the headers sent with your "page" are wrong. I suggest you post those response headers here, then maybe we can help.

Comment: Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: #slider_row
Date: Sun, 27 Sep 2015 12:23:33 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Powered-By: PrestaShop
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: xxlplanD=R14834053; path=/; expires=Sun, 27-Sep-2015 12:24:55 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.38
p3p: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"

Comment: You're right arkascha, #slider_row is definitely not an existing mime-type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As supposed by arkascha (thank you arkascha), the headers sent with my page were wrong.
The file product.tpl of my prestashop theme contained a line:

```
{header('Content-Type: #slider_row')}
```

I replaced this line by:

```
{header('Content-Type: text/html')}
```

And now, it works fine. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. BTW: My name is "arkascha" :-)